# "[WinError 126] The specified module could not be found". Can I fix Anaconda without a full reinstall?

Tags: windows-10, installation, python, anaconda

When installing tensorflow with `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow` I get:

> ## Package Plan ##
>
> environment location: C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3
>
> added / updated specs:
> - tensorflow
>
> The following packages will be downloaded:
>
> ```
> package                    |            build
> ---------------------------|-----------------
> _anaconda_depends-2020.07  |           py37_0           6 KB
> anaconda-custom            |           py37_1           3 KB
> archspec-0.1.1             |     pyh9f0ad1d_0          25 KB  conda-forge
> ca-certificates-2020.6.20  |       hecda079_0         184 KB  conda-forge
> conda-4.8.4                |   py37hc8dfbb8_1         3.1 MB  conda-forge
> openssl-1.1.1g             |       he774522_1         5.7 MB  conda-forge
> ------------------------------------------------------------
>                                        Total:         9.0 MB
> ```
>
> The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
>
> _anaconda_depends
> pkgs/main/win-64::_anaconda_depends-2020.07-py37_0   absl-py
> conda-forge/win-64::absl-py-0.9.0-py37hc8dfbb8_1   archspec
> conda-forge/noarch::archspec-0.1.1-pyh9f0ad1d_0   astor
> conda-forge/noarch::astor-0.8.1-pyh9f0ad1d_0   conda
> conda-forge/win-64::conda-4.8.4-py37hc8dfbb8_1   gast
> conda-forge/noarch::gast-0.4.0-pyh9f0ad1d_0   google-pasta
> conda-forge/noarch::google-pasta-0.2.0-pyh8c360ce_0   grpcio
> conda-forge/win-64::grpcio-1.31.0-py37h554427f_0   keras-applications
> conda-forge/noarch::keras-applications-1.0.8-py_1   keras-preprocessi~
> conda-forge/noarch::keras-preprocessing-1.1.0-py_0   libprotobuf
> conda-forge/win-64::libprotobuf-3.12.4-h200bbdf_0   markdown
> conda-forge/noarch::markdown-3.2.2-py_0   openssl
> conda-forge/win-64::openssl-1.1.1g-he774522_1   protobuf
> conda-forge/win-64::protobuf-3.12.4-py37h1834ac0_0   python_abi
> conda-forge/win-64::python_abi-3.7-1_cp37m   tensorboard
> conda-forge/win-64::tensorboard-1.14.0-py37_0   tensorflow
> conda-forge/win-64::tensorflow-1.14.0-h1f41ff6_0   tensorflow-base
> conda-forge/win-64::tensorflow-base-1.14.0-py37hc8dfbb8_0
> tensorflow-estima~
> conda-forge/win-64::tensorflow-estimator-1.14.0-py37h5ca1d4c_0
> termcolor          conda-forge/noarch::termcolor-1.1.0-py_2
>
> The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority
> channel:
>
> ca-certificates    pkgs/main::ca-certificates-2020.6.24-0 -->
> conda-forge::ca-certificates-2020.6.20-hecda079_0
>
> The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
>
> anaconda                                   2020.07-py37_0 -->
> custom-py37_1
>
> Proceed ([y]/n)? y
>
> Downloading and Extracting Packages conda-4.8.4          | 3.1 MB    |
> |   0%
> _anaconda_depends-20 | 6 KB      |                                                                               |   0% anaconda-custom      | 3 KB      |
> |   0% archspec-0.1.1       | 25 KB     |
> |   0% openssl-1.1.1g       | 5.7 MB    |
> |   0% ca-certificates-2020 | 184 KB    |
> |   0%
>
> [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
>
> [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
>
> [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
>
> [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
>
> [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
>
> [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

After this, I tried a few installs, without success:

- `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow` (again)
- `conda update --all`
- `conda install anaconda openssl`

Every try had again the error

> [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

**How can I fix this "WinError 126" without a reinstall of Anaconda?**

*Context:*

Force-closing the tensorflow installation had first caused an HTTP error which was then fixed, see ["force-close" during installation causes "CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED"](https://superuser.com/questions/1579263/force-close-during-installation-causes-condahttperror-http-000-connection-fa/1579264#1579264). This error here appeared after the fix of the HTTP error.

Comment: Your question isn’t clear.  The accepted answer to that SO answer seems to be clear.  What makes you think it was necessary to reinstall Python or Anaconda?  Yes;  Adding the path to the directory that contains the DLL is the correct solution to the error you received.  Please edit your question, to make it clear, what your question is exactly since it’s not about the “module could not be found” based on your last sentence.  Reinstalling Python or Anaconda isn’t the correct solution to this problem, it’s only a solution, for those who don’t understand the cause of the error in the first place.

Comment: @Ramhound I am not sure how to keep up this question since I cannot test the answer, and it is just something that has cost me the whole day without a final fix. Only reinstall was my solution, which is a bad one and which is not the answer that I am searching for. And the other things that I have not tried and looked promising were actually for the first HTTP error that I could fix with the dll trick anyway.

Comment: We are not a discussion forum, so documenting your problem, doesn’t really translate into a Question with an Answer.  It wasn’t even clear you had solved your problem, only you had one problem, but solved that only to encounter a different error.  If you were to edit your question to make it clear, what your question is exactly, somebody might answer it.  However, the existing answers on Stack Overflow, likely would be used as a reference (specifically the accepted answer to the question you linked to)

Comment: @Ramhound I have moved the documentation into another Q/A https://superuser.com/questions/1579263/force-close-during-installation-causes-condahttperror-http-000-connection-fa/1579264#1579264, hope that clears up this question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Intro:**

Tough this answer refers to the already existing answers on Stack Overflow, it might still help someone finding it in the context of the question.

As I did not check any of the solutions but reinstalled Anaconda instead, I cannot confirm that this answer provides the solution, yet I see the "promising solution" as promising enough to post an answer. Whoever has this problem, please comment or answer whether it helped you.

**Main:**

1. Promising solution:

The same error can be seen here, for example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60593240/problem-updating-bokeh-winerror-126-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found with a promising answer, linking to https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9313.

There, you find:

> It's a library load issue. More details at
> github.com/conda/conda/issues/8836 You probably have a broken conda
> right now. You can use a standalone conda from
> repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/misc/conda-execs to repair it:
> standalone-conda.exe update -p C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
> conda-package-handling You should get version 1.6.0, and the problems
> should go away.

Thus, it might simply be a conda issue. Reinstalling standalone conda might repair the error.

2. Other solutions:

There are highly voted questions of the same error message around, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940578/windowserror-error-126-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found.

The answer of "Doo Dah" might provide a solution to the question here, too, it shows you how to check which DLL causes the problem. But even if that was a solution, it is not a comfortable one, I rather do not expect the normal user to become a DLL professional only to solve the error here.