# "force-close" during installation causes "CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED"

Tags: windows-10, installation, python, http, anaconda

I closed the running process by force-closing the anaconda command prompt while it was actively installing tensorflow.

After this, running the tensorflow installer again, I got:

> (base) C:\Users\Admin>conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
> Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed
>
> CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url
> https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json
> Elapsed: -
>
> An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL. HTTP errors
> are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
> 'https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64'

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I share the steps to get to the solution, and I am documenting the unsuccessful steps as well since those unsuccessful steps might work in another context even when they did not work in my context.

First unsuccessful steps, following answers of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50125472/issues-with-installing-python-libraries-on-windows-condahttperror-http-000-co and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563757/conda-update-condahttperror-http-none:

- `conda config --set ssl_verify no`
- check that no conda is in the PATH variable (I had none anyway)

Then a succesful step:

I searched libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll in `C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\`
to find it in `C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\pkgs\openssl-1.1.1g-he774522_0\Library\bin`
(and not in `C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\Library\bin` as the forums are saying)

Then after copying

- libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
- libssl-1_1-x64.dll

[image]

to `C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\DLLs`, the first HTTP error was gone.

That is why I have not tried https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6007#issuecomment-467457872 by adding to PATH variable the following (which might have solved this as well, not tried):

- C:\Users\Anaconda3\Scripts
- C:\Users\Anaconda3\
- C:\Users\Anaconda3\Library\bin -- This is the directory for openssl

The previous list is just to show what I have *not* tried but what might have been a solution not only for the HTTP error, but perhaps even for the next problem with a lot of luck.

Anyway, copying the DLLs fixed this first HTTP error.